# Calling a Javascript/JQuery function on postback for ASP.NET/C# page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

I am working with a JQuery plugin called 'Tab Slide Out' a link is here: http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/

I am trying to use it as a feedback technique.  On the slide out there is a form, and a submit button.  Now when you hit submit, it of course causes a postback, and the page loads, but the feedback window is set back to its closed state.  I want the window to be automatically open on postback.  Here is an example of a website that uses the plugin and has it working how I want it to work: http://thedemo.ca/

Now I noticed in there script they have this on initial page load:

```
jQuery('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
  tabHandle: '.handle',
  pathToTabImage: 'typo3conf/ext/stw_jquery_feedback/images/feedback-btn-right.png', 
  imageWidth: '32px',
  imageHeight: '167px',
  tabLocation: 'right',
  speed: 300,
  action: 'click',
  topPos: '200px',
  fixedPosition: true,
  onLoadSlideOut: false
});
```

And then this on postback from the submit button:

```
jQuery('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
  tabHandle: '.handle',
  pathToTabImage: 'typo3conf/ext/stw_jquery_feedback/images/feedback-btn-right.png', 
  imageWidth: '32px',
  imageHeight: '167px',
  tabLocation: 'right',
  speed: 300,
  action: 'click',
  topPos: '200px',
  fixedPosition: true,
  onLoadSlideOut: true
});
```

Notice the last option of `onLoadSlideOut` changes.  How is this possible?  With that said I think the simplest solution would be to call click on the tabHandle, in turn sliding out the tab.

So I guess my real question is, how can I call click the .handle.

Here is a link to my test environment of my code: http://jakeism.info/test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are rendering the script dynamically. In asp.net the simplest way to do this would be something in your aspx/ascx like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
  tabHandle: '.handle',
  pathToTabImage: 'typo3conf/ext/stw_jquery_feedback/images/feedback-btn-right.png', 
  imageWidth: '32px',
  imageHeight: '167px',
  tabLocation: 'right',
  speed: 300,
  action: 'click',
  topPos: '200px',
  fixedPosition: true,
  onLoadSlideOut: <% Response.Write(Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false") %>
}); 
</script>
```

Note the scriptlet for `onLoadSlideOut`. Now that logic probably won't do exactly what you want -e.g. any postback would cause it to be rendered open. So just substitute whatever is appropriate as a condition.

A nicer way to do this would be to post to a `WebService` using ajax, instead of posting the whole page, so you don't have a postback at all. Then just cleanly close the slideout after letting the user know that their feedback has been received.

Comment: I guess this could be a whole entire new question but I don't know if its a simple answer or not.  How could I check if the postback is from a specific button inside of a scriplet?

Comment: You need to capture the event from the button, e.g. create a `SubmitFeedback_OnClick` event in codebehind, and set some flag there.

Comment: So it would execute the onlcick code behind then execute the the scriplet? Specifically in that order?

Comment: Any code you put in markup like that will execute after everything in codebehind, during rendering.

Comment: So if I set a variable named "string feedbackFlag;" how would I be able to access from a scriplet? <% Response.Write(Page.feedbackFlag) %> or something like that?

Comment: Well probably a `bool` would make more sense, and if it's called `feedbackFlag` then you would just say `Response.Write(feedbackFlag ? "true" : "false")` or possibly even `Response.Write(feedbackFlag.ToString())`

Comment: thanks for ur help and my problem solved. now i am facing another problem for flickering. when page load then for few sec all elements are showing inside my div called <div class="slide-out-div"></div>. so how to solve this problem......any idea.

Comment: set `display:none` for the initial style maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're best bet is to do the submission through an ajax call as you can then do some client side validation etc. and if successful you can slide it back in. The world is your oyster.

I'd recommend this route as if someone visits your site without javascript enabled the functionality will be limited, and your postback method will work fine (assuming the box is displayed automatically if not hidden on load of the page).